# Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facade\Mail' not found in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I get this error message while trying to send email (Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facade\Mail' not found).
in the controller, I have included 'use Illuminate\Support\Facade\Mail;' in the begining of the controller class (PostsController) and in the store function (of the controller), I have this

```
Mail::send('welcome_email', $data, function ($message) {
$message->from('walegbenga807@gmail.com', 'Coa Blog');

$message->to('nigeriawonderboy@gmail.com')->subject('There is a new post!');
});
return redirect('/')->with('status', 'ticket created');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to change the

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facade\Mail
```

to

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```

Comment: have added the s but new problem arises from it and this is the new problem.   'FatalErrorException in HandleExceptions.php line 59:
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded'

Comment: Which mail driver do you use? Have you set up anyone? [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail)

Comment: smtp. this is the .env conf for mail.         MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=my gmail address
MAIL_PASSWORD=my password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Comment: you may try encryption ssl

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a facade, just add this to the top of the class:

```
use Mail;
```

Or use full namespace when using the facade:

```
\Mail::send
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use 'use Illuminate\Support\Facade**s**\Mail';

Actually there is no Facade package, but **Facades**.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel don't know what is "Facade" but try adding **s** for Facade word.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

> use Illuminate\Support\Facade**s**\Mail;

For more about facades refer:
[Facades](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/facades#introduction)